# Find the limiting distribution of $Z_n=n[1−F(Y_n)],$ where $Y_n=\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question:

Given a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\},$ and function $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ suppose the followings:

(1) $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent for all $n$

(2) $X_n$ is a continous random variable for all $n$

(3) $F$ is the cdf of $X_n$ for all $n$

Show that $Z_n\to1$ in distribution, where $Z_n=n(1-F(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}))$ for all $n.$

=> I repeated to solve this question again and again but the only thing I got is:

$F_{Z_n}(z)=1$ if $z\ge n,$ $F_{Z_n}(z)=(z/n)^n$ if $0<z<n,$ $F_{Z_n}(z)=0$ if $0\ge z$

(which means that $F_{Z_n}\to0,$ and so $Z_n$ can not converges to $1$ in distribution.)

Can somebody help me from this dilemma?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $F_{z_n}(z)$ to $F_{Z_n}(z),$ with a capital $Z$ in the subscript and lower-case in the argument. That is correct usage; what was there is not.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the notation.

Comment: Would you help me solve the question?